# Kivy Refresh Android Gallery

Tags: android, kivy, refresh, android-gallery

I have created an app that saves an image in the Android Gallery. However, this does move the file to the `DCIM` folder, the Gallery does not show this picture.

This is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.image import Image
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
from os import *


class SITApp(App):
    def build(self):
        request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
        return Button(text='Save Image', on_press=self.save)

    def save(self, button):
        try:
            mkdir('/sdcard/DCIM/Image Saving/')
            Image('test.png').save('/sdcard/DCIM/Image Saving/test.jpg')
        except Exception as e:
            button.text = str(e)


SITApp().run()
```

If anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to call some android api function to reindex the gallery.

Comment: Any idea how to/which one to call?